# Разделение строки по разделителям и вывод из массива

Tags: java

Вопрос следующий: на вход подается строка типа: "print ("Hello World"); end.", необходимо ее разделить полностью на слова. На выходе должно получиться: print hello world end. Далее каждое это слово будет сравниваться с другим массивом, который служит "словарем", после чего на экран будет выводиться значение каждого слова. Как реализовать Сплит строки + вывод получившегося массива?

```
String text;
        Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        text = textIn.nextLine();
        String[] arrText = text.split(",|.|;|:|'|");
        System.out.println(arrText);
        for (int i = 0; i< arrText.length; i++){
            System.out.println(arrText[i]);
        }
```

Необходимо для анализатора лексем. Нужно написать своеобразный транслятор программного языка на вымышленный. Как введенный текст разбить по словам? И вывести массив получившихся слов?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала заменить все знаки типа ,.;:', на какой-то один например запятую, типа так

```
someText.replace(";",",");
```

А далее как у вас

```
String[] arrText = text.split(",");
```

arrText должен будет содержать все ваши слова

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не эффективно, но работает.
Для добавления новых символов, которые могут быть разделителями, просто добавте их в массив `symbols`

```
String text;
Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
text = textIn.nextLine();
// определяем массив символов являющихся разделителями
char[] symbols = {',',
                  '.',
                  ':',
                  ';',
                  '\\',
                  '(',
                  ')',
                  '"',
                  ' ',
                  '\''};
// приводим все разделители к единому формату
for (char symbol : symbols){
    text = text.replace(symbol,',');
}
// отладочный вывод, можно убрать
System.out.println(text);
//заменяем все лишние символы, по которым split создат отдельные элементы
while (text.contains(",,")){
    text = text.replace(",,",",");
}
// создаем массив слов
String[] arrText = text.split(",");
// выводим массив слов
for (String tempText : arrText){
    System.out.println(tempText);
}
```